# Compiling Visual Studio Code Open Source Project

Tags: node.js, compilation, typescript, visual-studio-code, code-editor

I'm considering to contribute to visual studio code open project, but the only thing i want to try first is to compile it, but i don't exactly know how to compile it since i am new to node.js and somekind of it. Can someone tell me how to compile it? thanks.

Comment: this is a question best addressed to that project directly, not stackoverflow

Comment: ok then, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See our documentation for [How to Contribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute).